# How to use swipe down/scroll down in appium with java-client 7.0.0?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

This is the code I have, the code not working and console send this:
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18 to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement

i need swipe/scroll down.

```
TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(ApplicationLauncherAndroid.driver)
.tap(element(lblImagen))// first initialElement
.waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
.moveTo(element(elementoFinal)) final Element
.release();
swipe.perform();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your source code - currently it's hard to read.  Furthermore please include a description of the problem: is the code not working or not compiling?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

use the following method for swiping in appium. Make sure you have imported from right library.

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
import static java.time.Duration.ofMillis;

//Vertical Swipe by percentages
    public void verticalSwipeByPercentages(double startPercentage, double endPercentage, double anchorPercentage) {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int anchor = (int) (size.width * anchorPercentage);
        int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPercentage);
        int endPoint = (int) (size.height * endPercentage);

        new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(PointOption.point(anchor, startPoint))
                .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofMillis(1000)))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(anchor, endPoint))
                .release().perform();
    }

    //Swipe by elements
    public void swipeByElements (MobileElement startElement, MobileElement endElement) {
        int startX = startElement.getLocation().getX() + (startElement.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
        int startY = startElement.getLocation().getY() + (startElement.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

        int endX = endElement.getLocation().getX() + (endElement.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
        int endY = endElement.getLocation().getY() + (endElement.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

        new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(PointOption.point(startX,startY))
                .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofMillis(1000)))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY))
                .release().perform();
    }
```

> It seems like you are importing wrong TouchAction. Import touch action from **io.appium.java_client.TouchAction**

Comment: i try this code, but i have a this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement field qa.automated.web.bci.Pages.pageMercadoLibre.precio to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18

Comment: Can you show me the code in **qa.automated.web.bci.Pages.pageMercadoLibre.precio** package? Instead of **AndroidElement** you can try **MobileElement**.

Comment: https://github.com/piter721/pruebaScroll , in branch: "pruebaScrollTheApp", src->text->generic->scrollElement | or src->text->definition->scrollApp

Comment: The problem is with your page object implementation. Use page object model like [this](https://blog.testproject.io/2018/07/31/page-object-model-appium-java-android/#POM_Appium)

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro Perez Aballay, hi . 
I'd suggest to go using the following alternatives:

- option A: client - [ElementListSelect](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/ElementListSelect)

(works only for instrumented apps - and on ListViews) - uses the app’s internal API, and is similar to the way that scrollIntoView works on web, though it requires instrumentation doesn’t work on all types of scroll views \ screens

- Option B: 
  TouchAction - e.g

  `TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
      WebElement phone = driver.findElement(in.Repo.obj("apps.Phone"));
      WebElement contact = driver.findElement(in.Repo.obj("apps.Contacts"));
      touchAction.press(phone)
      .waitAction(200)
      .moveTo(contact)
      .release()
      .perform();`
- Option C:   [client - SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SwipeWhileNotFound+Command)
- Option D: executeScript and specify that you want to perform a [swipe action](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Swipe).

Syntax:

```
driver.executeScript("client:client.swipeWhileNotFound(\"direction\", offset, time);
```

Example of doing a swipe up from the border of the screen for 500ms:

```
driver.executeScript("experitest:client.swipe(\"Up\", 0, 500)");
```

Parameters:

Direction: The direction to do the swipe (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT)
Offset: Position in the screen where the swipe starts
Time: Duration of the swipe (lower = faster swipe)

**Please note**

The values (time \ offset) are usually calculated as parameters from the device screen size e.g -

```
int offset = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() / 2; // start from mid screen
int time = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() * 0.3; // just an example
```

Hope this help,

Best regards,

Eugene